# Yii local to online implementation

Tags: yii

I am new to Yii and I wonder if it is at all possible to install Yii locally and build an application with it , then without installing Yii to your server or webhosting , upload the files and get the application into use ?

Comment: yes..  is possible ...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to install anything. Just make sure the entire directory (including the framework obviously) is uploaded to whatever web hosting you are using. Having PHP installed on the server should be the only requirement so make sure it's there.